# Domination of a differentiable bounded function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity

**Problem**

> Let $f$ be a function bounded from $\mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^+$, such that $f(0)=0$.

> Prove that $\exists C>0,\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^+, f(x)\leqslant Cx$.

**My attempt**

The problem comes when the derivate of the function is discontinuous in $0$, as for $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x^2)$. And then I really can't see how to prove the assertion.
I know I can dominate with an affine function using uniform continuity, but it doesn't help since we must dominate with a linear function.

Could someone help ?

Comment: The existence of $f'(0)$ together with $f(0) = 0$ implies that $f(x)/x$ is bounded in some interval $[0, a]$. For $x > a$ you use that $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** $$ \frac{f(x)}{x}
 = \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} $$
Since $f$ is differentiable this tends to a finite limit for $x\to 0$.